# Understanding ていなされる

Tags: grammar

> 「クレナが出てったら、シン、絶対どっか行っちゃったじゃん。会話にならないんじゃそりゃ文字通り話になんないよ」
>
> 「女の子には死んでも弱いところを見せないって謎の見栄が、男の子にはあるものね」
>
> 「……ああうんアンジュ。そうなんだけどそう言われるとなんか、もやっとするからやめてくれる？　あとソレ、別に男に限った話じゃないよね。女子だってそうじゃん」
>
> 「まあね」
>
> 婉然と笑っ**ていなされる**のを、少し面白くなくセオは見上げる。
>
> 86─エイティシックス─Ep.3 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈下〉 安里アサト

Is the bold part passive form of ていなさる, which in turn comes from ている? How should I understand this なさる? Or is the active form ていなす? I’m a bit confused by it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 笑って + いなされる.

いなされる is the passive form of the verb いなす. From 明鏡国語辞典:

> いなす【▽往なす・▽去なす】〘他五〙
> ❸ 攻撃や追及を軽くあしらう。「反論をいなして本題に入る」

And from [プログレッシブ和英中辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%BE%80%E3%81%AA%E3%81%99/):

> いなす【▲往なす】
> 彼は私たちの追及をいなした
> 〔軽くあしらう〕He treated our questions lightly.
> 〔軽くかわす〕He easily dodged [parried] our questions.